# Rotated Image Orientation of Cellphone Pictures

Tags: python, html, image, orientation, exif

I'm trying to display images on a simple html page, but it looks as though the image orientation of many of my pictures are rotated to the left, because they were taken by cellphone. The images are hosted on my computer.

I tried the css property image-orientation: from-image; but to no avail.
I used python's piexif library as well as PIL library to strip EXIF data, but the new stripped images still are rotated to the left.

I really feel as if there should be some simpler, standardized method of neutralizing the orientation of all of my images so that they naturally display upright?

Answer (score 2):

Rotate and remove 'Orientation' of exif value.

http://piexif.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample.html#rotate-image-by-exif-orientation